# Prettify json in powershell 3

Tags: json, powershell, powershell-3.0

Given a standard json string value:

```
$jsonString = '{ "baz": "quuz", "cow": [ "moo", "cud" ], "foo": "bar" }'
```

How can I get this to be all pretty with newlines, preferably without brute-force regex?

Simplest method I've found so far is:

```
$jsonString | ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertTo-Json
```

However, that seems kinda silly.

Comment: What is silly about the method you provided? Any other method will be either more complicated, or require an external module/library.

Comment: It seems silly because it's taking a json string, doing all the work to convert it to an object, then converting it right back. I was hoping there was something obvious I missed like `Format-Xml`

Comment: `Format-XML` is a PSCX command, and I believe it does the same thing by converting a string to an XML object then converts back to a string.

Comment: To minify any serialized entity, it has to be first be parsed (if only lexically). Only then does minification work, as the semantics are preserved.

Comment: Doesn't even work.  ConvertFrom-Json in powershell 5.1 does not support -AsHashtable, so plan on crashing a lot.  Use the Newtonsoft answer below

Comment: Json arrays will not round trip correctly through ConvertFrom-Json and ConvertTo-Json. This `[ { "hello": 1 } ]` becomes `{ "value": [ { "hello": 1 } ], "Count": 1 }`. @TechSpud's NewtonSoft approach is better

Comment: What's silly? I find it very sleek actually.

Answer (score 31):

Works for me.  Parentheses make sure get-content is done before piping.  Default depth of convertto-json is 2, which is often too low.

```
function pjson ($jsonfile) {
  (get-content $jsonfile) | convertfrom-json | convertto-json -depth 100 | 
    set-content $jsonfile
}
```

Comment: This seems pretty key, the depth parameter was the issue in my case.

Answer (score 17):

I put this in my profile

```bsh
function PrettyPrintJson {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        $json
    )
    $json | ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100
}
```

Which works with pipes, and can be auto-completed, so it's at least somewhat less typing:

```bsh
cat .\file.json | PrettyPrintJson
curl https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json | PrettyPrintJson
```

Comment: This is my favorite solution. Easy and short.

Comment: I like it, it works for me, personally, but I would like to create a little script that I can check into source control for others to work.  Appending the function to the top of the ps1 script isn't working, would you be a kind sole and put the two code blocks into one block that could be run from a ps1 script?

Comment: fits perfectly into `$profile`, thanks!

Answer (score 13):

If you really don't want to go down the simplest route, which is to use inbuilt PowerShell functions `| ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertTo-Json`, here is another method, using JSON.net

```
# http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx
Add-Type -Path "DRIVE:\path\to\Newtonsoft.Json.dll"

$jsonString = '{ "baz": "quuz", "cow": [ "moo", "cud" ], "foo": "bar" }'
[Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject]::Parse($jsonString).ToString()
```

Comment: Which is exactly the same technic only done with dotnet classes. ;-)

Comment: To support Arrays as well as Objects, use JToken, i.e. `[Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken]::Parse($jsonString).ToString()`

Answer (score 6):

Adding to @JS2010's answer I added logic to escape out certain characters and clean up my output even further.  The parenthesis seems key and `-depth` is a big one since you can lose details without it, from what I've seen, on depth that goes beyond the default of 5, I believe it is.

```js
function Format-Json ($JSON)
{
    $PrettifiedJSON = ($JSON) | convertfrom-json | convertto-json -depth 100 | ForEach-Object { [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Unescape($_) }
    $PrettifiedJSON
}
```

Comment: The default `-Depth` is `2`. It's unclear why you need parentheses here. Note that unescaping will result in invalid JSON; e.g. `[regex]::Unescape('{ "foo": "Nat \"King\" Cole" }') | ConvertFrom-Json`. If the intent is to turn, say, `\n` escape sequences into actual newlines, note that while `ConvertFrom-Json` _tolerates_ such string-internal newlines, they're not standards-conformant, and Node.Js, for instance, balks.

Answer (score -3):

I think what you are looking for is this:

```
$jsonString = @{ 
'baz' = 'quuz'
'cow'= "moo, cud"
'foo'= "bar" 
}
$jsonString|ConvertTo-Json
```

it produces this output

```
{
    "baz":  "quuz",
    "cow":  "moo, cud",
    "foo":  "bar"
}
```

**Added note**
You could also array your cow values to "prettify" it a bit more:

```
 $jsonString = @{ 
    'baz' = 'quuz'
    'cow'= @("moo"; "cud")
    'foo'= "bar" 
    }
```

output:

```
{
    "baz":  "quuz",
    "cow":  [
                "moo",
                "cud"
            ],
    "foo":  "bar"
}
```

Comment: Your `$jsonString` is really a powershell object. This doesn't solve the problem.