# JSON Prettifier Using Azure Function w/ PowerShell and HTTP Trigger

Tags: json, powershell, azure-functions, prettify

Thought this would be pretty simple, but alas, I can't figure it out. [It appears that PowerShell will prettify JSON with a single cmdlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24789365/prettify-json-in-powershell-3).

**Goal**: Prettify JSON using a PowerShell Azure Function app

- Using Microsoft Flow, send an HTTP request (POST) to an Azure Function w/ "ugly", serialized JSON file in body
- Azure Function reads file in (then uses `ConvertToJson` cmdlet to prettify?) and outputs the file back to Flow

**Questions**:

1. What do I put in the `run.ps1` area of the Azure Function to make this happen?
   [image]
2. What do I put in the `functions.json` area of the Azure Function to make this happen?
   [image]

Comment: GET Methods will discard the body of a request, so that rules out Get. You could use Post or PUT, both are for sending body contents to a web server.  Traditionally PUT and PATCH are for update statements, while POST could be used for Update or Create.

Comment: Thank you; I'll use POST. Any PowerShell syntax recommendations for actually knocking this out?

Answer (score 1):

I have taken below serialize string

```
'{ "baz": "quuz", "cow": [ "moo", "cud" ], "foo": "bar" }'
```

which was mentioned in [Prettify json in powershell 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24789365/prettify-json-in-powershell-3)

Here is my function which i used with HttpPost and send the request:

```
using namespace System.Net

# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)

# Write to the Azure Functions log stream.
Write-Host "PowerShell HTTP trigger function processed a request."

# Interact with query parameters or the body of the request.
$name = $Request.Query.baz
if (-not $name) {
    $name = $Request.Body.baz
}

if ($name) {
    $status = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
    $body = "Hello $name"
}
else {
    $status = [HttpStatusCode]::BadRequest
    $body = "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body."
}

# Associate values to output bindings by calling 'Push-OutputBinding'.
Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
    StatusCode = $status
    Body = $body
})
```

and below you can see , i am able to read it from the string which i posted.

[image]

You can use **`ConvertFrom-Json`** to convert it but i wondering if you even need it as you can access it by doing below:

```
$name = $Request.Query.baz
```

my binding is same as yours. Hope it helps.

Let me know if you still need any help.

Comment: Please note in the OP, I'm POST'ing a file of serialized JSON to the Azure Function rather than a string. Ideally, I'd like to get a prettified JSON file as output in the response. How does this change the PowerShell code?

Comment: still no luck for me. Status 400 Bad Request: "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body."
Again, I'm sending a FILE to the function NOT a JSON string. Any further ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
using namespace System.Net

param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)

Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
    StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
    Body = $Request.RawBody | ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertTo-Json
})
```