# How to send a .json file from Flow to Azure Function and return results?

Tags: json, azure, powershell, azure-functions

I want to send a serialized .json file to a PowerShell Azure Function, **prettify** it, then return the file to Flow for further processing. I cannot figure out how to do this.

**In Flow:**

- **Trigger**: Button push
- **Action1**: Get file content from OneDrive

  - **Output**:

```
    {
      "$content-type": "application/octet-stream",
      "$content": "eyJUb3BQYXJlbnQiOns...<truncated for this post>"
    }
```

- **Action2**: Send HTTP Request

  - **URI**: `https://test.azurewebsites.net/api/prettifyJson?code=<api key>`
  - **Method**: POST
  - **Body**: `body('Get_file_content')` (output from Action1)

**In Azure Function**:

- **Default PowerShell `run.ps1`**:

```
using namespace System.Net

# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)

# Write to the Azure Functions log stream.
Write-Host "PowerShell HTTP trigger function processed a request."

# Interact with body of the request.
$content = $Request.Query.baz
if (-not $name) {
    $name = $Request.Body.baz
}

if ($name) {
    $status = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
    $body = "Hello $name"
}
else {
    $status = [HttpStatusCode]::BadRequest
    $body = "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body."
}

# Associate values to output bindings by calling 'Push-OutputBinding'.
Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
    StatusCode = $status
    Body = $content
})
```

**Issues:**

1. A call to the function fails with `Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body.` I can see why, but do not know what syntax to replace in `run.ps1`
2. I have no idea what syntax to use to:

   a. Receive the .json file

   b. Convert it to pretty json

   c. Repackage the .json file

   d. Send it back to Flow

Looking for guidance.

Answer (score 1):

About number one, seems you're missing the name in the url.

try to replace from this:

https://test.azurewebsites.net/api/prettifyJson?code=

to this:

https://test.azurewebsites.net/api/prettifyJson?name=test&code=

about your second question, the you'll need to parse the body content as Hashtable. try to combine:

$hash = $Request.Body | ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable

then all the variables will be available using $hash[]

e.g: $hash["$content"]

Comment: Thanks @Thiago. I replaced `$content = $Request.Query.baz` with `$hash = $Request.Body | ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable`. Will you advise on how to complete the `run.ps1` file with the correct substitutions?

Comment: what else you azure function needs to do?

Comment: Nothing, just prettify the JSON. My understanding is that PowerShell automatically prettifies serial JSON when its opened. I'm not even sure if ConvertFrom/To-JSON is required.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24789365/prettify-json-in-powershell-3

Comment: I've seen this. It only addresses opening a STRING of json in local instance of PowerShell. I need to know the syntax for interacting with a FILE of json in an Azure Function.

Comment: all you need to do is replace the string to the content (which will contain your file). | $Request.Body  | ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertTo-Json