# Formatting json output from docker events

Tags: powershell, docker, jq

I want the docker events output to be more readable. 
Am on windows 10 pro, and on a powershell I run this command.

> docker events --format "{{json .}}"

In a different shell when I create a new container,

> docker create mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1

I get some output in json format in the first shell. And that looks something like this.

> {"status":"create","id":"7897095c22919bcdcf39612386bebed63296bc33be250445e6069bf4fe90ce37","from":"mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1","Type":"container","Action":"create","Actor":{"ID":"7897095c22919bcdcf39612386bebed63296bc33be250445e6069bf4fe90ce37","Attributes":{"image":"mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1","name":"objective_bhaskara"}},"scope":"local","time":1585135301,"timeNano":1585135301351718800}

My question is, is there a better way to format that? What should I do to the command

> docker events --format "{{json .}}"

So that it will be formatted in a more readable way. Is there something to pipe that output so that it may look something like the following. I used some online formatter to get to this.

[image: docker event output formatted]

**UPDATE**

Its now resolved.

As per @Vijay's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60848171/1977871), I first installed [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/). The steps are:

1. Ran power shell as admin.
2. Ran the command [choco install jq](https://chocolatey.org/packages/jq)
3. Opened a new command prompt **NOT** powershell. Somehow power shell did not work.
4. Issue a command to listen to [docker events](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/events/).
5. If the output has to be [formatted](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/events/#format-the-output), use the command. Also append jq as follows. Note the double quotes("). Single quotes(') did not work.

> docker events --format "{{json .}}" | jq

6. Open another prompt and run the following command. This can be a powershell if you wish.

> docker run hello-world

7. You should now see formatted json output streaming real time.

Comment: You can use my `Format-Json` function I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56324939/9898643)

Comment: You can add `| ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertTo-Json` in that command as well. [ConvertFrom-Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prettify json in powershell 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24789365/prettify-json-in-powershell-3)

Comment: The output is kinda streaming, so they are not working. No output comes once I use a pipe and then weather I use jq or ConvertFrom-Json etc

Comment: "*kinda streaming" is not a showstopper, you can stop a stream (and load the full `json` file into memory) by using brackets or assign the stream to a variable.

Comment: Don't know docker, but if you capture the json output in a variable and pipe that through to [Format-Json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56324939/9898643) you should get a nice human readable result.  `$json | Format-Json`

Comment: @VivekDev thanks for pointing that its NOT working in Powershell. Issue solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just pipe in `jq` to your `docker events` command.

```
docker events --format '{{json .}}' | jq
```

[jq Documentation](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/jq-command-json)

Comment: I think I need to install jq first. Let me check. I am getting jq : The term 'jq' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

Comment: yeah... once you do, it will just give you the expected output.

Comment: Installed, but no output comes, not sure why

Comment: @VivekDev no output for docker events or for piping jq ?

Comment: Once i pipe it through jq I get no output. So this does not give any output          docker events --format '{{json .}}' | jq

Comment: Are you doing any docker stuff in parallel?

Comment: Two points. Single quote did not work. Only double quote. Also powershell did not work. Only humble command prompt.

Comment: Found this note about Powershell in the docker documentation https://docs.docker.com/config/formatting/. In a Windows shell (for example, PowerShell), you need to use single quotes, but escape the double quotes inside the params as follows: `docker inspect --format '{{join .Args \" , \"}}'`.

Answer (score 1):

Using the first answer form [Prettify json in powershell 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44593864/1701026):

```
$Json = '{"status":"create","id":"7897095c22919bcdcf39612386bebed63296bc33be250445e6069bf4fe90ce37","from":"mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1","Type":"container","Action":"create","Actor":{"ID":"7897095c22919bcdcf39612386bebed63296bc33be250445e6069bf4fe90ce37","Attributes":{"image":"mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1","name":"objective_bhaskara"}},"scope":"local","time":1585135301,"timeNano":1585135301351718800}'
$PrettyJson = $Json | convertfrom-json | convertto-json -depth 100
$PrettyJson
```

Result:

```
{
  "status": "create",
  "id": "7897095c22919bcdcf39612386bebed63296bc33be250445e6069bf4fe90ce37",
  "from": "mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1",
  "Type": "container",
  "Action": "create",
  "Actor": {
    "ID": "7897095c22919bcdcf39612386bebed63296bc33be250445e6069bf4fe90ce37",
    "Attributes": {
      "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1",
      "name": "objective_bhaskara"
    }
  },
  "scope": "local",
  "time": 1585135301,
  "timeNano": 1585135301351718800
}
```